# Change Color of Text inside a block

Tags: color, links

I want change the color of a word in a block.
I used `colorlinks`, but the links will be coloured by the default colour is `red`.

```
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
}


\cventry{08 July 2018}{Machine Learning}{....}{......}{}{
\begin{itemize}%
\item This course provides a broad introduction to......
\item Supervised learning (......).
\item Unsupervised learning (......).
\newline{}
\item \href{https://www.google.com/}{google.com}
\end{itemize}
}
```

How can I change the color Blue ?
Thank you

Comment: In which block? Please proved a complete MWE.

Comment: The "google.com" is displayed RED I want it's color is Blue.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Some minimal working example related informations you can find here: ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linkcolor` sets the colour of internal links within the document. If you want to change the colour of `\href`, you have to change the `urlcolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue
}

\begin{document}

\href{https://www.google.com/}{google.com}


\end{document}
```